# About the boundary of a fibered cone of a 3-manifold

Tags: 3-manifolds, teichmuller-theory

Let $S$ be a closed surface, $\psi$ a pseudo-Anosov map, $M$ be the mapping torus, $\tilde{S}$ be a $\mathbb{Z}$-fold cover of $S$ using an invariant cohomology class. Let $D$ be a fundamental domain, $H$ be the deck transformation, and $\tilde{\psi}$ be a lifting of $\psi$ on $\tilde{S}$. Now let $N(p)=\sup\{n: H^nD\cap \tilde{\psi}^p(D)\not=\emptyset\}-\inf\{n: H^nD\cap \tilde{\psi}^p(D)\not=\emptyset\}$. Is it true that the asymptotic growth rate $\lim_{p\rightarrow\infty}{N(p)\over p}$ can always be computed through the shape of the fibered face of $M$?

Comment: How does $\tilde{\psi}$ act on $\widetilde{M}$? Doesn't it preserve $D$?

Comment: $\psi$ preserves the subgroup $\pi_1(\tilde{M})\subset \pi_1(M)$ so there is a lifting, however the lifting is not unique and two liftings differ by a power of $H$ hence $N(p)$ is well defined. If it preserves $D$ it would preserve the boundary curve of $D$ which become some curve in $M$ under the covering map, which contradicts with the pseudo-Anosov assumption.